Where are the pure colors on CIE diagram?
Where are the pure colors on CIE diagram?
I think that they are only along the curved edge.
Are the colors in the 'straight line of purples' also considered as pure colors?
Are pure colors only along the curved edge or along the edges?


What do you mean by "pure colors"?

There's different chromaticity diagrams. Some of them present the color producing capability of some printing or display system and some presents the color perception capability of humans or some imaging system. I guess this one is just the diagram for the human color perception capability.
The meaning of term "pure color" is not at all unique. One says that they are red, green and blue because they have the highest possible chroma levels in RGB color displays.
But when one writes of human color perception capability he often tells that pure colors are those which can be produced by showing to a person a light which contains only a single wavelength between 380 and 700 nanometers. If your diagram presents the color perception capability of humans, those single wavelength colors are on the curved part of the edge of the flatiron shape. The bottom straight edge presents color sensations which cannot be created by any single wavelength light and in that sense they are not pure colors. But they are still certain hues which have the highest possible perceived chroma (that's the distance from as bright colorless grey) and in that sense someone can well call also them pure colors. The right answer in your exam depends on what the lectures has declared to be the meaning of therm "pure color". That declaration can well vary between schools, books and  individual lecturers.
The colors inside the flatiron shape are not the colors of the points on the diagram. They only roughly present the available visible hues. A scientifically valid chromaticity diagram shows properly the the color coordinate numbers of the flatiron shape edge points and the coordinates of the white point in the middle. The used color coordinate system, of course, is exactly defined. The scientifically valid diagram can be printed on paper by using only black ink. Printed colors can well be replaced by inserting a collection of color names or codes in some generally accepted color numbering system (Munsell, Pantone)
Often the curved edge has also the corresponding wavelengths for color sensations which are created by using a single wavelength light.

You're right to guess that the colors on the curvy edge are special in some sense! I'll try to give you a more precise answer based on some textbooks I've read such as Zuppiroli's Traité des couleurs.

In nature, rays of light can have various energies or wavelength. If you isolate some rays with the same wavelength, you'll always see the same hue. That is why such a beam of light is called monochromatic (from the ancient greek for "one color"). This is more of a physics temrinology, and the mathematics behind that can be elaborated by talking about the spectrum of the light. Because monochromatic light has only one energy/hue among the whole possible spectrum, the corresponding colors are called spectral colors. That is the proper name you seem to be looking for the colors along the curved edge of the CIE chromaticity diagram.
As you can guess then, most colors (all the ones in the bulk of the diagram) are not spectral. They are obtained by mixing spectral colors in various amounts. In real life, almost all colors we see are not spectral!
Among the colors that are not spectral, aspectral colors are another limiting case that correspond to the colors on the straight edge of the CIE diagram (or, depending on conventions, to the triangle delimited by this edge and by the white point in the bulk). Aspectral colors are more precisely the boundary to human vision, in the sense that colors beyond would be a combination of colors beyond blue (so, ultra-violet) and beyond red (infrared), which could not be visible to a human eye.

Hope that answers your question, feel free to leave a comment if you want to clarify any point!
Two other links you might be interested in:
Spectral colors on Wikipédia
Line of purple on Wikipédia

Generally, it would be preferable not to call them colors. It would be better to characterize the curved portion as dirac-delta spectral distribution (aka single wavelenght)*. Because otherwise you get into the semantics of what color means and it gets messy fast and you get into really weird ideas of how things work.
This is why its called a chromaticity chart. Not a color chart. It sort of maps physics observations with human color vision. It does not make a value judgement as to wether a color is discernible from another (some of them uniquely are, some apparently not) just how it maps to light phenomena.
The straight line portion is not a dirac delta, as there is no wavelength that ties short waves to long waves. But instead the line is violet-blue and red together.
None of our common imaging technologies work by manipulating wavelengths. Since our eyes dont see wavelenghts as such (although it indirectly does to some extent) thy do instead work by manipulating eyes sensors which are not spectrometers so dont require more than 3 signals.
* The main problem is that people expect things to be two directional road. So saying a wavelength has a color is correct, but it does not follow that wavelengths are colors. Colors are what humans percieve and the transfer to brain signals is not a 1:1 mapping of physics.
